# Yii what is "controller views "?

Tags: php, yii

I am reading the Yii URL management in Yii's online guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url.

One line says:

> Although URLs can be hardcoded in **controller views**, it is often more
>   flexible to create them dynamically:
>   $url=$this->createUrl($route,$params);
>   .....

The term "controller views" is really new to me. I often hear "in Views", "in Model", "in Controller", but never "in Controller Views". Could you help me understand this term? Is it "controller" or "views" or the one that's completely different to the three things above?

Comment: Googling "yii controller view" gives 283,000 results. Including [yii controller view](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc) as number 3 result. Really?

Comment: Yes, I have read the link you gave above already. But none of them explain "controller view", I mean, I understand what "controller" or "view" is, but term with combination "controller views" as I mention in my QUESTION that maybe easy to misunderstand. Could you help me with this new term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context *controller view* just means the *view*, that part of the guide is really trying to tell you that you shouldn't hard code urls anywhere if at all avoidable.

It's more of a convenience thing rather than an MVC / Yii rule. If you hard code the urls, and you change the layout or url structure of your app in future, then you'll have to go back through your whole app changing every instance of your hard coded urls, much easier to use `createUrl()` and let that deal with any changes in future.

(i.e. the red box note immediately above the [creating urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#creating-urls) section you mention)